I'm trying to replace text in all files using FIND
$i%2==0 ? $color="$c[color7]" : $color="$c[color7]";
I'm trying to change all files like this.
$i%2==0 ? $color="$c['color7']" : $color="$c['color7']";
find . -name "test3.php" -exec perl -pi -e 's/\$c\[color7\]/\$c\['color7'\]/g' {} \;

In my test file it didn't change to $c['color7'].
Change it when inserting " as shown below.
' <-- does not change.
find . -name "test3.php" -exec perl -pi -e 's/\$c\[color7]/\$c\["color7"]/g' {} \;


I solved it like this:
find . -name "test3.php" -exec perl -pi -e "s/\$c\[color7]/\$c\['color7']/g" {} \;

